# Does the character with the following properties exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Given a proper subvariety $V\subseteq G_m^n$ (V is also a subgroup). Can we always find a character $\chi:G_m^n\to G_m$ which is a morphism and a group homomorphism such that $V\subseteq \ker\chi$?

Comment: Not unless you allow the trivial character (in which case the kernel is everything). For an easy example, take $n=1$, say over complex numbers and let $V$ be just one non-torsion point. Any non-trivial character is finite and thus the kernel is finite, which can not contain a non-torsion point.

Comment: What about if I further assume $V$ is a subgroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $G_m$ dennotes the multiplicative group over some nice field, in my mind it's algebraically closed of characteristic zero. In this case, what you ask is true. In fact, this is a property of diagonalizable groups. You get the following from, e.g., Corollary 22.5.4 in the very nice book "*Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups*" by Tauvel & Yu:

> **Theorem**. Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G_m^n$. Then:
>
> 1. $H$ is diagonalizable
> 2. There exist characters $\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_n\in \mathbb{X}(G_m^n)$ s.t. $H=\ker\chi_1\cap\cdots\cap\ker\chi_n$.
> 3. If $\theta\in\mathbb{X}(H)$ is a character of $H$, then there is a $\chi\in\mathbb{X}(G_m^n)$ such that $\chi|_H=\theta$.

You get what you want as a corollary.